# Laravel how to validate request class but not in method parameter

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my case, I got a Request Class which I create using artisan :

```
php artisan make:request StoreSomethingRequest
```

Then I put my rules there, and then I can use it in my Controller method like this:

```
public function store(StoreSomethingRequest $request)
{

}
```

But what I need is, I want to separate 2 Request logic based on the button in my view (Assumes there is more than 1 submit button in my view). So my controller will look like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   if($request->submit_button === 'button1')
   {
      // I want to validate using StoreSomethingRequest here
   }
   else
   {
      // I dont want to validate anything here
   }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestion / help. Please. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in your request class inside rules method.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'common_parameter_1' => 'rule:rule',
        'common_parameter_2' => 'rule:rule',
    ];

    if($this->submit_button === 'button1')
    {
        $rules['custom_parameter_for_button_1'] = 'rule:rule';
    }
    else
    {
        $rules['custom_parameter_for_button_2'] = 'rule:rule';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have more complicated validation in the request class. I have an after rules validation there. Not simply return the rules.

Comment: Then you should be more constructive about the question.

Comment: yes, sorry that's my fault to not be constructive. But, is there a way to achieve it? Any suggestion would be great. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rajender, I just need to set the logic inside my Request Class. I can add condition in it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` and `value` attributes on the HTML submit buttons. Then check which one has been submitted. Example:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="button1">Save 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="button2">Save 2</button>
```

Then in the handler:

```
 If (Request::input('action') === 'button1') { 
//do action 1
 } else { 
// do action 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erin, but how to use the StoreSomethingRequest Class in the "Do action 1 or 2" ? I want to validate it there.